# How can I set the Navigation tab to bookmarks Panel and Page

Tags: jasper-reports, itext

I'm generating a report using itext and creating bookmarks in the report. I would like the PDF to open with the bookmark section expanded. I can modify the properties of the document AFTER generation so that this occurs, but the PDF is generated by a batch process, so I want to add this into the generation.

I've tried using addViewerPreference(PdfName, PdfObject) but cannot seem to get this setting to work. I am able to use it to set other initial properties, but not this one.

I'm guessing that either that property isn't supported at all, or is not supported in the version of itext I'm using. I'm still using 2.1.7.

Comment: `addViewerPreference` was added in iText 1.4.9. `addViewPreference` on the other hand, does not exist.

Comment: sorry, typo on my part. addViewerPreference is what I am using. Updating the post.

Comment: As usual, after posting a question I'm able to solve it. I had to use PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines and setViewerPreferences(int) instead  addViewerPreference.